# Header wrapping to new line when each column is smaller than its size

Tags: reporting-services

I have a column breakout that has a header that is rather long.  The breakout always has more than one column (usually 12, one for each month).

My title is:  "2012 Forecasts", so I would like it to look like this:

```
|                              2012 Forecasts
|Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | Jun | Jul | Aug | Sep | Oct | Nov | Dec |
```

The issue is that when I preview the report it looks like this:

```
|                              2012 Forecasts
|
|Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | Jun | Jul | Aug | Sep | Oct | Nov | Dec |
```

This is unacceptable formatting for this table, because there are many nested rows, which make the headers extremely large.

In experimenting for solutions, I noticed that making the length of the columns large enough to fit the string "2012 Forecasts",  makes the row size down.  However, by doing this my columns are way too wide.

Is there a way that I can force the column header not to wrap in this way

Answer (score 1):

In the properties of the header I set **CanGrow** to false, and it suppressed the new line